# Retrieving SamAccountName and associated groups in a formatted csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all Ad users matching a filter, pipe that into `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` and then export the result to an easy to read CSV.

*NB I can't use `MemberOf` as it returns blank for every single Ad user, and most successful scripts I've found are using `MemberOf`.

Here's what I've tried which gives me a list of groups but no association as to who goes where. Tried to `export-csv` as well but it complains of an empty pipe?

```
import-module activedirectory
foreach ($user in (Get-AdUser -Filter {(Name -Like "*(s)") }  | select samaccountName)) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.samaccountName | select samaccountname,name
}
```

Comment: Not getting anything returned for `MemberOf` is your real issue here as it's part of the standard schema. What happens if you run `Get-ADUser USERNAME -Properties MemberOf | Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf`

Comment: @James C , That actually does return results. Odd, when I did `Get-AdUser (filter) | ft name, samaccountname, memberof` earlier, it returned empty braces for the group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will include the user's `sAMAccountName` in the group results:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
ForEach ($user in (Get-AdUser -Filter {(Name -Like "*(s)") }  | select sAMAccountName)) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.sAMAccountName| select @{Expression={$user.sAMAccountName};Label="User"},sAMAccountName,name
}
```

That weird notation is for creating a custom table. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ee692794(v=technet.10)

Not seeing anything in `memberOf` may be normal. If you check in Users and Computers, do you see a value in `memberOf`?

The `memberOf` attribute will only show groups with a Universal scope in the same AD forest, Global groups on the same domain, or Domain Local groups on the same domain of the server you're reading from (which may not be the same domain as the user). So it has its limitations.

Users can also be "a member" of a group by the `primaryGroupId` attribute, which stores the RID (the last section of the SID) of the user's primary group. This is usually only used for the Domain Users group.

`Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` takes care of all of that for you. It will include the primary group and search every domain in your forest for Global and Domain Local groups that have the user as a member.

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Further reading is always appreciated!

That script actually output the group name twice so I trimmed it but at least I have a user-group mapping now, thank you. 

Still confused about the empty pipe scenario. I thought it was the braces breaking the pipe but the same issue occurs with the pipe inside the brace.