# How to search all groups to which user belong but using specific user attribute?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I want to search all groups to which user belongs but I have only user's sAMAccountName attribute and I have to do it in one query.

Following query works correctly but I do not know user CN, I only know user's sAMAccountName.

```
"(&(objectClass=Group)(member=CN=Mariusz Kulig,CN=Users,DC=krbtst2k8,DC=local))"
```

Following query also works correctly:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=mkulig))
```

How to get all groups by sAMAccountName ? I do not see any other attribute than **member** in Group object which points to User.

Comment: I found workaround which is specific for my case. I use Java application which connects to LDAP and this application allows to provide only one query to find all groups to which user belongs. In summary I find a way how to use user DN instead of sAMAccountName in this application so I use  query (&(objectClass=Group)(member=CN=Mariusz Kulig,CN=Users,DC=krbtst2k8,DC=local)) .

Answer (score 0):

Using LDAP you must use the DN which is returned from your filter:

> (&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=mkulig))

So it takes two queries.

Powershell has some tricks that will allow a one-liner. (But it makes the same two or more queries)

```
(Get-AdUser -Filter {(sAMAccountName=mkulig)}  | select sAMAccountName)) {
    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user.sAMAccountName| select @{Expression={$user.sAMAccountName};Label="User"},sAMAccountName,name
```

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50529848/88122

-jim

Comment: Thank you for help. I do not use Powershell. I use Java application which has some restriction - I can provide only one query which takes all groups to which user belongs. I found workaround.